# g++ compiling and while loop

Tags: c++, c++11

**Prerequisites:** Atom as code editor with gpp-compiler(plugin), that uses g++ to compile and run cpp files in the editor.
Some not real example code to understand the problem:

```
int main()
{
    int number;
    while(cin >> number)  
    {  
        cout << "Your number is " << number << endl;  
    }  
}
```

So this program can easily compile by g++ compiler, the problems appears at runtime, when compiled program starts in terminal and... It's just don't work. There is no something else but "Press any key to continue..." There is no even mistakes.
So the compiler cannot support this loop argument? (`while(cin>>number)`)
And yes, gpp-compiler in Atom works fine with other types of scripts.
Sorry, if this question is stupid but i just want to know why this happens. Thank you!

Some edits:
So yeah. I can't competently explain my problem. So my problem is not the while loop argument, i just don't understand why program starts in empty terminal(with message above), while on my phone it also compiles by g++ and the program works perfectly .-.

Comment: What is the expected result? What do you want this program to do

Comment: Add `cout<<"before loop";` before `int number;` and add `cout<<"in loop";` in the while and see what will happen.

Comment: So by this method I can easily solve some exercises from book(Prata C++ Primer 6th edition). And on Android(C4droid) my program successfully compiles without any mistakes(there is g++ compiler too), but on my PC I just watch empty Terminal:(

Comment: Have you learnt how to use the debugger yet?  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @UKMonkey, meh, the problem is not in code. Code doesn't matter right now. The problem is why after g++ compiling the program not just ignored such loop, but terminal is fully empty even if there is cout before the loop.

Comment: @S.Grinev the problem is most definately in the code, you just haven't worked out how to identify exactly why it is.  You managed to identify the where, but the why still illudes you.  Learning to use the debugger will help resolve this

Comment: The problem is in *your* code. You should trust the `g++` compiler (with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....), probably driven by some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) like `make` or [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/). Don't forget to compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`). **Use the debugger** `gdb`

Comment: BTW, provide some [MCVE] in your question (as indented code, four spaces at least in front of every line).

Comment: Meh, nevermind. Seems that i too stupid to explain my problem. So topic can be closed.

Comment: That code doesn't compile - what's `cin`, `cout` and `endl`?  If they should be  `std::cin`, `std::cout` and `std::endl`, then you need to import the relevant header, and use their full names.

Comment: @TobySpeight It's obvious, I just wanted to make code more laconic and readable .-.

Answer (score 1):

The `(cin >> number)` condition always evaluates to `true` until you send an EOF character to it. On Windows it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>. The reason you are not seeing anything on standard output is that the program waits for your to enter a value and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Afterwards it enters the endless loop. Modify your program to include some simple logic:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char choice = 'y';
    int number;
    while (std::cin && choice == 'y') {
        std::cout << "Enter the number: ";
        std::cin >> number;
        std::cout << "Your number is " << number << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Repeat? y / n: ";
        std::cin >> choice;
    }
}
```